# Accessing Servers without Port Forwarding

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding

So I'm stuck in a conundrum. I can't buy a server, and I'm stuck with this ISP who refuses to give me a new router. They have given me a ZTE Router (ISP is Cincinnati Bell FiOptics (great speeds though!)) and  I want to host a website on server I've built out of a Raspberry Pi link.

I can login, setup the port forward, says the port is open, but the router stops it from accessing the local network even though it's open, bound to the local IPs. I have tried DMZ but it screws up our television service.

I'd use a free VPN like Hamachi, but that's only tied to Hamachi users and I need this open.

Anyone have a solution?

Comment: The Router's Model is ZTE Broadband Router ZXHN_H368C

Comment: Router get public IP from ISP? You can look WAN IP in web interface.
You test connectivity from outside, not from router LAN?
Possible You misunderstood port forward in web interface, sometimes it kludge.

Comment: Works fine when I connect to the server via LAN. Also the description in the Router's Web Interface is very clear.

Comment: I describe in bad way. :-( You try connect to forwarded port on public IP of router from other public ip, not from Your lan?
Also, try use not port 80 and etc, popular ports can be blocked by ISP firewall. Try forward random high port.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the "Virtual Server" page?

Comment: Virtual Server Page #1: http://i.imgur.com/t37vOJw.png | Virtual Server Page #2: http://i.imgur.com/WKJsT9l.png

Comment: Those images both appear to contain no entries. How are you setting up the port forward if not via virtual servers?

Comment: These were taken before entry, I took them after my ISP told me to remove them and send a screenshot for some reason.

Comment: Please set it up again and post screenshots.

Comment: Adding a port: http://i.imgur.com/vTFzMDO.png | Port inputed: http://i.imgur.com/7EBGEP4.png - CanYouSeeMe shows that 8080 is open.

Comment: Okay, so what happens when you go to http://[WAN_IP_HERE]:8080/ ?

Comment: Also, are you testing from inside your LAN or outside?  Try from a device not connected to the local network.  If that works you might need to add another NAT rule for internal clients.

Comment: Nothing will connect, that's the issue with port forwarding. I can connect via LAN, but not through my IP Address or WAN.